# Solr Extended DisMax doesn't add the scores of phrase queries any more

Tags: solr, edismax

I upgraded from **Solr 4.4.0** to **5.1.0** and I noticed a different behaviour from the Extended DisMax Query Parser when a phrase query matches in several fields.

With **4.4.0**, if a phrase query matches in field1 and in field2, then the sum of both boost will be used to boost the score of the document.

With **5.1.0**, only the maximum value of the matches in different fields gets used to boost the score of the document.

Is there any way to influence this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using the [`tie` parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#tie_.28Tie_breaker.29)?

Comment: No I don't. But I also did not use the tie parameter when I used solr 4.4.0. But as I understand this parameter it will influence not only the boost from the phrase query but from all matches. Or can I somehow specify, that it only influences the phrase query matches?